# Как получить массив с указателями/именами на все классы-потомки базового

Tags: c++, массивы, ооп, классы

Имеется некий класс `A` и его потомки `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, `A4`, `A5` и т.д. Также есть класс `B`, в котором должна быть функция `F`, возвращающая массив с именами/указателями на `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, `A4`, `A5`...

Важное правило: нельзя создавать объекты классов `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, `A4`, `A5` раньше, чем вызвана та самая функция `F` из класса `B`.

По сути (хотя это уже не касается задачи), в этой функции класса `B` будет вторая функция `K`, которая будет создавать объекты по указателям из массива, возвращяемые в неё из `F`.

Вот такая задача мне встретилась на практике. Гугл к сожалению не понимает меня (или я его).

Примечение

.H

```
TSubclassOf<YourClass> BlueprintVar; // YourClass is the base class that your blueprint uses
```

.CPP

```
     ClassThatWillSpawnTheBlueprint::ClassThatWillSpawnTheBlueprint(const class FPostConstructInitializeProperties& PCIP)
 : Super(PCIP)
  {
       static ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<UBlueprint> PutNameHere(TEXT("Blueprint'/Path/To/Your/Blueprint/BP.BP'"));
       if (PutNameHere.Object) {
            BlueprintVar = (UClass*)PutNameHere.Object->GeneratedClass;
       }
  }
```

Comment: Из коробки никак. C++ не поддерживает рефлексию. Составляйте список в ручном или полуавтоматическом режиме.

Comment: Полуавтоматический режим это что-то вроде назвать класы A1,A2,A3,A4,A5 а потом циклом типа (A%n),n

Comment: Например, так. Любое решение покатит, официального поддерживаемого языком решения нет.

Comment: Просто мне нужно в массив засунуть около несколько сотен указателей и вызывать объекты случайным образом. Выходит, что хардкодить прийдёться

Comment: В принципе, можно _сгенерировать_ нужный код маленькой программой. Тогда захардкодить придётся только в одном месте — списке аргументов на входе генератора.

Comment: @AntonIvanov, если у Вас так много классов и различие в их функционале не столь велики, то может быть имеет смысл подумать об иной архитектуре? Как правило такой хардкод совершенно неоправдан и возможно найти другое решение.

Comment: @alexis031182: Это может быть например тест, а классы как бы спущены сверху.

Comment: @Vlad, если я правильно понял Вас, то даже если тест, то вопросы теста могут быть организованы в классы, например, по типу ответа, когда требуется вручную что-то написать или выбрать один из прилагаемого списка вариантов. То есть произвести разделение не на уровне вопроса, а на уровне взаимодействия с пользователем. Тогда вариаций типов будет значительно меньше.

Comment: @alexis031182: Я имел в виду, что ТС, возможно, имплементирует unit test для уже существующего кода, и не может влиять на структуру классов.

Comment: @VladD, понял Вас, да, не подумал об этом.

Comment: Нет, у меня другая проблема(только не закидывайте какахами). Я использую UnrealEngine и мне нужны патерны(шаблоны) для генератора уровня (то есть из них он будет склеивать уровень). Я могу просто создать 2 структуры и 2 таблицы (одна таблица будет ссылкаться на другую ->  в итоге двухмерный массив) А далее уже на основе этих данные генерировать и тогда мне не нужна будет куча классов. Но к сожалению, что бы было удобно работать  с таблицой у меня есть (как я вижу) 2 варианта: создать свой MapEditor и через него работать.

Comment: Или работать нативно через асеты. А каждый асет это класс и мне нужен массив с ними, что бы можно было создавать объекты, которые выберет генератор. Других возможностей я не вижу. Потому, что мне будет удобно если в папке будет штук 500 разных шаблонов лежать, я могу заходить каждый и прям в нативном редакторе менять их.

Comment: Я, как и гугл, Вас не понимаю. Приведите пример, псевдокодом, чтобы было понятно.

Comment: Unreal Engine позволяет работать не С++ напрямую,а через Blueprint . В нативном редакторе можно создавать эти принты, в них например будут объекты игровые в определнном положении со своими параметрами. Каждый такой принт это будущий шаблон. Но вот через принты нельзя обратиться ко всем наследникам класса, если они без объектов. А мне как раз и нужен массив с классами (принатами), а моя функция будет выбирать нужный класс и создавать объекты и всё это в рантайм понятное дело. 

Поскольку классов много, то не хотелось бы хардкодить. 
Хотя я могу просто вбить руками ссылки и можно не париться.

Comment: Ну приведите Вы пример на псевдокоде, напишите в нём то поведение, что Вы хотите. Можно тысячу раз объяснять словами, но лучше один раз привести конкретный пример.

Comment: @ixSci Окей, я на с++ приведу, смотрите в конце вопроса добавил.
Суть в том, что для каждого класса  ядолжен писать типа 
 `static ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<UBlueprint> PutNameHere(TEXT("Blueprint'/Path/To/Your/Blueprint/BP.BP'"));`
и в итоге я уже могу спаунить объекты разных классов, но дело это очень быдлокодное как помне. Писать вначале файла 500 подобных строк кода  и заносить в масив. Да ещё и только в конструкторе можно писать только. Короче говоря это будет массив указателей и создавать наверное мне его придётся вручную из-за особенности языка с++

Comment: Вот это имена! Пока до конца дочитаешь -- начало уже забыл...

Comment: Спасибо все кто откликнулся, реально благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А, так у вас есть список некоторых файлов в некоторой папке - и каждому из них соответствует класс? Это меняет дело.

Здесь может пригодиться автогенерация кода сторонними средствами. Берете любой интерпретируемый язык программирования (хотя можно и на С++ писать) - и пишите программу, которая получает список файлов из указанной директории и генерирует из них `.cpp` файл нужного вам формата. Потом этот файл добавляется в список единиц компиляции основной программы.

Возможно, здесь вам потребуется выучить способ обращения хоть с какой-нибудь системой сборки проектов. Традиционно в C++ используется `make` или его *почти* совместимый аналог `nmake` - но можно использовать и что-нибудь другое. Хорошим выбором будет использование системы построения, которая уже используется вашей IDE. Это позволит, к примеру, не перечислять файлы, лежащие в папке - а получить их список от IDE - что снимает проблемы вида "файл исключен из проекта - но все равно влияет на результат сборки".

Впрочем, это не обязательно - можно обойтись и обычным пакетным файломи / bash-скриптом.

Генерируя код, надо понимать два правила.

1. Автогенерированный быдлокод быдлокодом не считается. Серьезно: когда автогенерация заработает - никому не будет интересно заглядывать в сгенерированный файл. Поэтому его читаемость человеком не нужна. Повторение одинаковых конструкций также допустимо - это человек делает при копипасте ошибки, компьютер таких ошибок не допускает.
2. При использовании систем контроля версий автогенерированный файл, также как и любые выходные и промежуточные файлы проекта, в систему контроля версий не включается. Вместо этого в системе контроля версий должна присутствовать программа, позволяющая автогенерированный файл воссоздать.

Answer (score 1):

Я так и не понял, всё-таки, задачи, поэтому представляю решение того, что я понял.

> Имеется некий класс A и его потомки A1, A2, A3, A4, A5 и т.д

```
class A
{
public:
    A(std::string path):
        m_Path(path)
    {
    }
    virtual ~A()
    {

    }
    std::string path() const
    {
        return m_Path;
    }
    virtual std::unique_ptr<A> clone() = 0;
private:
    std::string m_Path;
};

class A1: public A
{
    using A::A;

public:
    std::unique_ptr<A> clone() override
    {
        return std::unique_ptr<A>{new A1{path()}};
    }
};

class A2 : public A
{
    using A::A;

public:
    std::unique_ptr<A> clone() override
    {
        return std::unique_ptr<A>{new A2{path()}};
    }
};
```

> Также есть класс B, в котором должна быть функция F, возвращающая
>   массив с именами/указателями на A1, A2, A3, A4, A5...

```
class B
{
public:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> f()
    {
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> vec;
        vec.push_back(std::make_shared<A1>("first path"));
        vec.push_back(std::make_shared<A2>("second path"));
    }

    //..
};
```

> По сути (хотя это уже не касается задачи), в этой функции класса B
>   будет вторая функция K, которая будет создавать объекты по указателям
>   из массива, возвращяемые в неё из F.

```
class B
{
public:
    //..

    void k()
    {
        auto vec = f();
        decltype(vec) anotherVec;
        for(auto item: vec)
        {
            anotherVec.push_back(item->clone());
        }
    }
};
```

Это то, что я понял, если я понял не так, то поясните, чего в вышеприведённому коде Вам не хватает, попробуем разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

Средств сделать такое автоматически язык не предоставляет. Но можно, по крайней мере, разбить список на элементы и вынести их куда-нибудь по-ближе к объявлениям классов. В таком случае добавлять и удалять классы станет в некотором роде проще.

Возьмем вот такой вот класс:

```
class registry_entry {
    // поля и виртуальные функции, которые понадобятся классу B
};

// Осторожно, не создавайте этот класс на стеке!
template<T> class registry_entry<T> : registry_entry  {
public:
    registry_entry() { B::registerClass(typeid(T), this); }

    // а тут реализация виртуальных функций
};
```

Теперь, при реализации класса `A5`, мы регистрируем этот класс в той же единице компиляции, где реализован его конструктор:

```
static registry_entry<A5> entry;
A5::A5(...) {
    ...
}
```

Осталось реализовать метод `B::registerClass`. При его реализации надо быть внимательным - поскольку компилятор не гарантирует порядок инициализации глобальных и статических переменных, в этом методе нельзя полагаться на то, что конструкторы у глобальных и статических переменных успеют отработать. Вероятно, тут пригодится паттерн ленивой инициализации.

Comment: Поскольку для задачи ТС нужно создавать экземпляры классов, то возможно регистрировать надо factory — то есть прагматически функцию, создающую экземпляр класса. Возможно, тут надо будет «досыпать» метапрограммирования в каком-то виде.

Comment: Если формат конструктора известен заранее - то нет никаких причин разводить метапрограммирование, достаточно одного абстрактного метода в `registry_entry`.

Comment: В принципе, если все конструкторы синтаксически одинаковы, то и абстрактный метод не нужен. `registry_entry() { map[typeid(T)] = []() { return new T(); } }`.

Comment: Ну, это уже лямбда, причем с динамическим связыванием. Да, так делать можно - но выгод это никаких не даст. А без лишних лямбд код все-таки читается немного проще (элементарно, меньше уровней вложенности).

Comment: Ну хорошо, вот вам без лямбды: `registry_entry() { map[typeid(T)] = this; } Base* create() { return new T(); }`. Хотя это наверное уже и есть абстрактный метод. // Собственно, это по сути и есть ваш код.