# Как получить объект со случайного дочернего класса?

Tags: c++, ооп

К примеру я имею базовый класс "А" и его потомков Б1,Б2 и так далее очень много.

Я хочу написать что-то вроде:

```
A *randomobject1;
randomobject1 = A::Getrandomobject();
```

В итоге randomobject1 это указатель на какой-то объект из дочерних классов (Б1, Б2 и тд)

Мне не так сильно интересует рандомный доступ, сколько сама его реализация. Получается где-то нужно ссылки на методы дочерних классов или как это реализовать?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/425108/10105

Answer (score 3):

В конструкторе базового класса пишешь код, который сохраняет в статический контейнер указатель на this, а в Getrandomobject выбираешь случайный элемент этого контейнера.
А в деструкторе, соответственно, удаляешь указатель из контейнера

Answer (score 2):

Регистрацию типов сделать не сложно, главное определится, где делать эту регистрацию.
Предлагаю следующий вариант:

Создаём класс `A`:

```
class A
{
public:    
    ~A()
    {

    }

    template<typename T>
    static void registerType()
    {
        if(m_RegisteredTypes.find(typeid(T).name()) == m_RegisteredTypes.end())
        {
            m_Creators.push_back([]{ return std::make_shared<T>(); });
            m_RegisteredTypes.emplace(typeid(T).name());
        }
    }

    static std::shared_ptr<A> getRandomObject()
    {
        std::random_device device;
        std::mt19937 generator(device());
        std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> dist(0, m_Creators.size() - 1);
        auto number = dist(generator);
        return m_Creators[number]();
    }
private:
    using Creator_t = std::function<std::shared_ptr<A>()>;
private:
    static std::vector<Creator_t> m_Creators;
    static std::unordered_set<std::string> m_RegisteredTypes;
};
```

Здесь мы определили статический метод, который будет регистрировать метод создания какого-либо класса и ассоциировать его с именем этого класса. Почему не использовать `std::map` вместо двух классов? Можно и его использовать, просто его не так удобно скрещивать с функцией `getRandomObject()`.

Теперь где-нибудь вызываем следующий код для регистрации наших типов:

```
A::registerType<B1>();
A::registerType<B2>();
// и т.д.
```

После этого можно смело вызывать `A::getRandomObject()` получая случайный объект. Основным ограничением вышесказанного является тот факт, что объекты создаются без параметров, т.е. с помощью конструктора по умолчанию. Но это можно изменить, при желании.

Привожу полный пример, но имейте ввиду, что я там использовал макросы для генерации классов и вспомогательную функцию, чтобы меньше писать при регистрации, они Вам могут быть без надобности. Я использовал всё это для сокращения писанины:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
    }

    ~A()
    {

    }

    template<typename T>
    static void registerType()
    {
        if(m_RegisteredTypes.find(typeid(T).name()) == m_RegisteredTypes.end())
        {
            m_Creators.push_back([]{ return std::make_shared<T>(); });
            m_RegisteredTypes.emplace(typeid(T).name());
        }
    }

    static std::shared_ptr<A> getRandomObject()
    {
        std::random_device device;
        std::mt19937 generator(device());
        std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> dist(0, m_Creators.size() - 1);
        return m_Creators[dist(generator)]();
    }

    virtual void print()
    {
        std::cout << "A class";
    }
private:
    using Creator_t = std::function<std::shared_ptr<A>()>;
private:
    static std::vector<Creator_t> m_Creators;
    static std::unordered_set<std::string> m_RegisteredTypes;
};

//Это нужно будет вынести в cpp файл. Я этого не делаю, т.к. у меня всего одни файл.
std::vector<A::Creator_t> A::m_Creators;
std::unordered_set<std::string> A::m_RegisteredTypes;

#define STR(str) #str
#define DECLARE_CLASS(name) \
    class name: public A \
    {\
    public:\
        void print() override\
        {\
            std::cout << STR(name) " class\n"; \
        }\
    };

DECLARE_CLASS(B1)
DECLARE_CLASS(B2)
DECLARE_CLASS(B3)
DECLARE_CLASS(B4)
DECLARE_CLASS(B5)
DECLARE_CLASS(B6)
DECLARE_CLASS(B7)
DECLARE_CLASS(B8)

template<typename T>
void registerTypes()
{
    A::registerType<T>();
}

template<typename T1, typename T2,  typename... Tail>
void registerTypes()
{
    A::registerType<T1>();
    registerTypes<T2, Tail...>();
}

int main()
{
    registerTypes<B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7, B8>();
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        A::getRandomObject()->print();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Наверное так: у каждого класса создаётся статическая функция newObject - создание объекта данного класса, далее указатели на эти функции помещаются в список, ну и потом из этого списка выбираешь случайно и создатель объекты ....

Comment: Интересный вариант, я тоже так думал. Но возникает вопрос как динамички добавлять ссылки, на ту самую статическую функцию дочернего класса, в список?